# Is watching animes like Naruto haram?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk, cartoon

I watch Naruto, in that they use chakra as energy source or power, and they sometimes they commit act of shirk, whenever they do any kind of act of shirk, I start saying this all is fake and there is only one God and that is Allah, I do this because it's all fake first and second that this might lead me to commit shirk, but in the home we play like using techniques of the anime and chakra all that but we don't commit any act of shirk, we just play and we don't believe in it and one of my friends just thinks about a story like Naruto in which there is chakra but we all know it's fictional, are we committing shirk, and are we committing sin? We only watch these anime for entertainment.

Comment: We don't even need to complicate things. Naruto has music. Thus it is haram. It is the best that you don't even start to watch haram movies and animes because if you get hooked on to them, it is almost impossible to quit them. This is like alcohol. Most of us never drank alcohol Alhamdulillah. But those who drank it, I am pretty sure now that they know the fun of it, can't quit so easily.

Comment: Assalamualaikum, this question was actually asked by me like a year ago, and I actually have stopped watching anime and sometimes just watch 1 or 2 ep, I do know that addiction which you are talking about cause at one point I just wanted to watch Naruto but now alhamdulillah, I have overcome that addiction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question needs **diversified discussions** which may be broken down as below points!

---

1. Time Management
2. Islamic Views of Entainment
3. Slow poisoning
4. Cultural conflicts and conflicts in believed as well
5. Going  near to halal acts that (may) lead to sin(s)
6. Doing Meaningless tasks

---

I am giving very brief answers as keywords for further study or exploration for the curious mind!

1. Our HAYAT / time is the foremost grace from the Almighty alongside Iman! Wasting Time is a prohibited act in Islam!
2. Entertainment is a very basic human need. Acknowledging that, Islam doesn't restrict Muslims from enjoying themselves at leisure and allows various forms of entertainment as well eg. physical activities, listening to meaningful musicless non-instrumental nasheeds, watching and educational video production, and many more! But there are limits & guidelines for entertainment for a Muslim for which an act of entertainment may be equally be judged as prohibited or allowed with certain clauses eg playing football! If the players wear inappropriate clothing avoiding Islamic guidelines that aren't permitted. Men Watching women playing or vice versa avoiding Islamic guidelines of Veil that is also prohibited. If any bet is related to any gameplay that is prohibited as well.
3. Such videos/ animations are actively harming our beliefs, making us forgetful of our basic beliefs, and injecting agnosticism into our beliefs. Watching these meaningless non-educational or least educational video productions killing our valuable time as well.
4. Such many video productions are released as part of war-of-civilizations to have a greater effect on the opponent's mindsets.
5. Islam strongly discourages doing any act that may lead to sin which example can specifically be referred to [al-Isra’ 17:32].
6. Islam denounces doing any meaningless task investing health, time, wealth, or any other effort from which there is no worldly benefit or benefits for hereafter to a single human or Muslim.

Lastly, I would like to give an analogy as that is poured what is inside the pot! As a remarkable part of your entertainment time is being engaged there watching that video production you actively recall those memories when you are not watching that anime. Even you, maybe unknowingly from the subconscious mind, act with the line of their presentation when you play with your mates. Form this one can say how much impact, obviously negative, that anime had created upon you!

I don't know your age but I would like to suggest thinking upon the matter primarily with references to the above discussion than a deep sincere contemplation in yourself to identify the sincere Islamic Act for yourself!

> #Self_Declaration: I may not be totally right but I am open to discussions!

**May Allah, the Almighty grant both of us the right & beneficial knowledge, a practicing life, and finally His meeting at Heaven through granting His forgiveness at the Day of Judgment!**

*AsSalamu_Alaikum!*

Answer (score 0):

I asked something similar to my teacher (we have religion classes) and he said they are okay unless you actually lose your mind and believe that fictions. But I don't have any trusted sources.